# Find and replace using NSRegularExpression

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a string of format NSString *CalculationFormula = @"((Col(202)/Col(201)-1)*100";
I need to replace all occurrences of **Col(number)** with **ABC(number * 10)**

Please help ...

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some ambiguity in the desired results.  For example, should the result be "ABC(202 * 10)" or "ABC(2020)"?  I'm going to assume the latter.  Since regex is fairly generic, here's a Perl snippet that accomplishes what I think you want, followed by its translation into Cocoa.  I've given both, because it's much easier to see what's going on there before moving onto `NSRegularExpression` because the latter has so many more escapes in the pattern.

**Perl version:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;


my $search_text = "((Col(202)/Col(201)-1)*100";

$search_text =~ s|Col\((?P<num>\d+)\)|ABC($+{num}0)|g;
print $search_text;
```

Prints: `((ABC(2020)/ABC(2010)-1)*100`

So, the matching pattern is `Col\((?P<num>\d+)\)` and the substitution pattern `ABC($+{num}0`

**Cocoa version:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSRegularExpression *regex = nil;
    regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"Col\\((\\d+)\\)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSString *searchText = @"((Col(202)/Col(201)-1)*100";
    NSString *newText = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:searchText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,[searchText length]) withTemplate:@"ABC($10)"];
    NSLog(@"new = %@",newText);
    [p release];
}
```

Logs:

```
2012-09-18 12:30:26.880 Untitled[22405:707] new = ((ABC(2020)/ABC(2010)-1)*100
```

Now, if my original assumption was wrong and you literally want "num * 10" in the result,then the substitution pattern is:

```
@"ABC($1 * 10)"
```